# BGFX ignore shader

Tags: opengl, rendering, lwjgl, bgfx

I'm trying to code some game engine using Java, LWJGL and bgfx but have a problem with shaders. Currently I use OpenGL 2.1 backend.

For some reason bgfx rollbacks to the default shader program. I'm using very simple shader and it compiles without errors with shaderc, but when I supply it to the encoder with `bgfx_encoder_submit(encoder, 0, program, 0, 0)` bgfx seems to ignore it completely, as if I used `bgfx_encoder_submit(encoder, (short) 0, program, 0, 0)`.
What i'm doing wrong?

here's the code

**vertex shader**

```
$input a_position, a_texcoord0
$output v_texcoord0

#include "../common/common.sh"

void main()
{
    gl_Position = mul(u_modelViewProj, vec4(a_position, 1));
    v_texcoord0 = a_texcoord0;
}
```

**fragment shader**

```
$input v_texcoord0

#include "../common/common.sh"

SAMPLER2D(s_texColor,  0);

void main()
{
    vec4 color = texture2D(s_texColor, v_texcoord0);
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

**creating shader program**

```
short vertexShader = loadShader(vertexShaderName);
short fragmentShader = loadShader(fragmentShaderName);

this.program = bgfx_create_program(vertexShader, fragmentShader, true);
```

**render frame**

```
long encoder = bgfx_encoder_begin(false);
bgfx_encoder_set_transform(encoder,
             model.translation(position.x, position.y, position.z)
             .rotateXYZ(rotation.x, rotation.y, rotation.z)
             .get4x4(modelBuffer));

bgfx_encoder_set_vertex_buffer(encoder, 0, vertexBuffer, 0, vertexCount);
bgfx_encoder_set_index_buffer(encoder, indexBuffer, 0, indexCount);

bgfx_encoder_set_texture(encoder, 0, textureUniform, texture, 0xffffffff);

bgfx_encoder_set_state(encoder, BGFX_STATE_DEFAULT, 0);

bgfx_encoder_submit(encoder, 0, program, 0, 0);
bgfx_encoder_end(encoder);
```

**result**

expected just a texture without a color (see shader), but was a texture with a red color, as if default program was used. I tried to modify shader, but every time get the same result.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVzL9.png)

Answer (score 0):

For some strange reason first bgfx_encoder_submit call ignore passed shader program, subsequent calls use provided shaders as expected

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).